# How to restrict other file being uploaded except mp3 file

Tags: mp3

I Want to upload only mp3 files in my project but
When i change extension of an docs file to mp3 it is also uploading easily.
Could i get any code which restrict any such file being uploded..

Comment: which server side are you using? and btw if the extension is changed manually there's no way you can stop that